# IIS for Windows Server 2019

Tags: iis

I have windows server 2019, and classic asp.net 3.5 application ,when I add this application to IIS it only shows folders and do not run the application, I have followed the normal process ,add folder to wwroot ,add application ,change pool permission ,and every thing worked as expected but still am not able to browse my application

Comment: Have you enabled ASP.NET 3.5 role service?

Comment: Did you install the ASP.NET  3.5 and .NET Extensibility3.5 in turn on or off windows feature of control panel?

Comment: Yes, I selected from features. .NET Framework 3.5 (Includes .NET 2.0 and 3.0) (Installed). HTTP Activation (Installed)

Comment: In the windows server 2019  install the ASP.NET 3.5 and .NET Extensibility 3.5 in turn on or off windows feature of control panel. the same add features in the roles

Comment: Please check the handler mapping, whether asp handlers are enabled. Also try to disable the application's directory browsing.